# Passport object not getting appended in request object in Mac Safari browser

Tags: express, cookies, safari, passport.js, express-session

session and here is my configuration

```
app.use(session({
        secret: 'secretKey',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        rolling:'true',
        cookie:{
                secure:true,
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 1
        }
}));
```

with this config,I am able to login and use my app in Windows IE,EDGE,Chrome, and Mozilla

### Below is log for req.session after authentication for above mentioned browser

```
 Session {
     cookie: 
       { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true
       },
     passport: { user:{ username: 'admin', admin: '1', status: true } }      
    }
```

As you can see passport object is appended in request.session object

### Mac-Safari Log

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Thu Sep 07 2017 19:25:04 GMT+0530 (IST),
     originalMaxAge: 60000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true } 
    }
```

I don't understand why passport object is not getting appended in the request only in **MAC-Safari**.

Comment: Please note I am able to get passport object appended to the request object for **MAC-safari** if I remove  **maxAge** property

Comment: 'app.use(cookieParser()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
secret: 'quickhealSecretKey',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
rolling:'true',
cookie:{
secure:true,
httpOnly: true,// maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 1
}
})); 
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 
app.use(flash()); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + uiDir));'